# The top of jquery datepicker is not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Hi I am having an issue with the button panel in jQuery Datepicker. I am using the date picker in JQGrid and the top of the datepicker is not displaying correctly

[image: Screen Shot]

If the button panel displayed correctly I wouldn't care that it's there but its not. My code explicitly sets it to false so it should not be visible.

```
            {
            name: 'ExpirationDate', index: 'ExpirationDate', editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (el) {
                    $(el).datepicker({
                        showButtonPanel: false,
                        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        minDate: '+2D'
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
The more I look into this problem it is looking like this is a CSS issue, but I can't see any files missing. I'm using MVC4 and my scripts are bundled as follows

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

public static class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/css/MasterCss")
            .Include("~/content/bootstrap.css")
            .Include("~/content/bootstrap-responsive.css")
            .Include("~/content/css/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/jquery.jqGrid/jqgridcss")
            .Include("~/content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/themes/base/jqueryuicss")
            .Include("~/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")
            .Include("~/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/MasterScripts")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Validation")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/App/referencedata.validation.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Index")
            .Include("~/Scripts/App/splash.js"));
    }
}
```

and the bundles are called in the following layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>@ViewBag.Title - ReferenceDataManagement </title>
     @Styles.Render("~/content/css/MasterCss")
     @Styles.Render("~/content/jquery.jqGrid/jqgridcss")
     @Styles.Render("~/content/themes/base/jqueryuicss")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="max-width: 100% ;min-width: 1235px">
        <div class="row"> @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml") </div>
        <div class="row"> @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_menu.cshtml") </div>
        <div class="row"> @RenderBody() </div>
        <div class="row"> @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml") </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/MasterScripts")    
    @RenderSection("scriptholder", false)

    @MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes(RenderPosition.Right, false, false, 15, true)
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML output where the scripts are generated when the code is ran is

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/App/CodeListGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript" id="mini-profiler" src="/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=xwYPDDH1blvqmxgsBweNC++H7CFU3KGQ+zFcVlJPsXw=" data-version="xwYPDDH1blvqmxgsBweNC++H7CFU3KGQ+zFcVlJPsXw=" data-path="/mini-profiler-resources/" data-current-id="e19ebd5a-9b81-40f9-993a-545cd8dfc3ce" data-ids="e19ebd5a-9b81-40f9-993a-545cd8dfc3ce" data-position="right" data-trivial="false" data-children="false" data-max-traces="15" data-controls="true" data-authorized="true" data-toggle-shortcut="Alt+P" data-start-hidden="false"></script>
```

This code is directly before the   tag. From looking at the examples datepicker mine should look a lot neater and be smaller. I checked my custom css by removing it and I still had the same error so I left it out of this post.

Comment: Set jsfiddler to resolve the problem.

Comment: make a fiddle demo plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was definatly a css issue, I downloaded a new Jquery Ui theme and selected datepicker and added it to my project. Everything started to work after that and I have a nice new color scheme.

I would imagine that the datepicker css was not included properly in my css but I don't want to go through the css of the base jquery ui and figure out if it was included or not.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the code which you posted **don't contains** the button panel. If you would use `showButtonPanel: true` one would see the bar below the datepicker with buttons "Today" and "Done"

[image]

see the demo from "Display Button Bar" part of the Datepicker documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar). The datepicker on the picture which you posted don't contains the button bar, so all works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me, I had assumed that the button panel was the left / right buttons up the top. So now the question should be why is the top messed up for my code. I would imagine that this is a styling issue ?

Comment: @JeffFinn: You are welcome! I suppose that you have some CSS conflicts, but your question don't contains enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a quick play around with the css as far as I know we arn't using any custom css I remember seeing an autosize function somewhere for either jqgrid or datepicker. If that doesn't work. I'll try and figure out a better way of giving the required info to reproduce. I have to learn how to use that jsfiddle site